# poigné à attendre

Tags: sens, québec

J'ai un problème à comprendre "poigné à attendre" dans cette phrase:

> J'étais poigné à attendre mes clients toute la journée.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca/?hl=en#fr/en/poign%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20attendre): il ne aide pas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tout d'abord, le mot est *pogner* et il n'y a absolument pas la moindre justification pour l'écrire avec un *i* (bien que beaucoup trop d'ouvrages insistent sur ladite lettre).

C'est un québécisme et dans cette phrase il signifie "coincé, obligé de".